# How is $\text{PCP}[O(\log n),O(1)]$ NOT P?

Tags: complexity-theory, p-vs-np

As a prover, we just try to convince the verifier that it's correct, no matter whether it is or not. So we can just analyze every possible route.

For $\text{PCP}[O(\log n),O(1)]$, won't there just be polynomial many possible routes, and checking all just cost polynomial time?

> In computational complexity theory, an interactive proof system is an abstract machine that models computation as the exchange of messages between two parties. The parties, the verifier and the prover, interact by exchanging messages in order to ascertain whether a given string belongs to a language or not. The prover is all-powerful and possesses unlimited computational resources, but cannot be trusted, while the verifier has bounded computation power. Messages are sent between the verifier and prover until the verifier has an answer to the problem and has "convinced" itself that it is correct.

Comment: You have copied an informal definition. Looking at the formal definition instead could clarify matters.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Which one is the formal definition?

Comment: I understand it as "Both verifier and prover get the input, verifier is a TM with special functions that: send bit to prover(for unlimited times); generate random bits(for logorithm times); recieve bit from prover(for constant times), and verifier can be programmed to run for polynomial steps. Prover can do anything. Verifier can be programmed such that, if answer is TRUE, some prover always make verifier accept, and if answer is FALSE, all prover at least make verifier reject for half of time"

Comment: The (somewhat) formal definition can be found on the same Wikipedia page, under [Definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistically_checkable_proof#Definition).

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Read definition which says that "the verifier is **nonadaptive**, runs in polynomial time, and it has randomness complexity r(n) and query complexity q(n). ", which makes it more likely to be P

Comment: The verifier runs in P, just like in the definition of NP. You could say the same about SAT. Does it also belong to P?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus for NP there are exponential possibilities, but here it's only polynomial possibilities

Comment: It’s the same here. There are exponentially many possible proofs.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus It seems to fall into what `randomness complexity`(as I understand it as random bits verifier can obtain) and `query complexity`(as I understand it as bits verifier can obtain from prover) are. If I understand correctly there's no exponentially many possible proofs at all.

Comment: You’re missing the point. An input is in the language if there’s a proof which convinces the verifier. The proof has polynomial length, so there are exponentially many proofs. The definition of “convinces” depends on *all* bits of the proof. We don’t consider just one possible set of queries - we consider all of them at once.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus but the queries only differ because of different random bits, which is already shown as the probabilist

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Looks like you are still trying to claim "PCP=NP so PCP≠P", and do assumptions on the NP part

Comment: Let me update the answer later with some more details on the definition of PCP.

Comment: Read some more info and get your "exponentially many possible proofs" mean: if prover is just a random access TM, it needs a proof stored to quickly answer the queries. However, it's also fine to work it out during the interaction, as long as it doesn't take much time(maybe it's a super computer or something) @YuvalFilmus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A language $L$ is in $\mathsf{PCP}(r(n),q(n))$ if there is a randomized polytime algorithm $V(x,y)$ which acts as follows:

- The algorithm is given $r(n)$ random bits.
- Given these random bits, it chooses (deterministically) $q(n)$ locations in $y$.
- It reads $y$ at these locations, and based on that, decides whether to accept or reject.

Furthermore, $V$ satisfies the following two conditions:

- If $x \in L$ then there exists $y$ such that $\Pr[V(x,y) \text{ accepts}] = 1$.
- If $x \notin L$ then for any $y$, $\Pr[V(x,y) \text{ accepts}] \leq 1/2$.

Let $n = |x|$. Since $V$ uses only $r(n)$ random bits and reads at most $q(n)$ bits of $y$, at most $2^{r(n)} q(n)$ bits of $y$ can potentially be read. when $r(n) = O(\log n)$ and $q(n) = O(1)$, this means that at most polynomially many bits are read from $y$, and so we can assume that $y$ has polynomial length.

Every language in $\mathsf{PCP}(O(\log n), O(1))$ is in $\mathsf{NP}$. Indeed, given $y$, we can compute $\Pr[V(x,y)\text{ accepts}]$ in polynomial time (since there are only polynomially many choices for the random bits). However, the language is not obviously in $\mathsf{P}$, since there are exponentially many choices for $y$.

Comment: Currently I don't ask for a "proof", but only try to convince, so the amount of potential proofs doesn't matter

Comment: Answers to different “routes” must be consistent, in the sense that they come from an underlying proof. This is part of the definition of PCP. You can’t make it go away.

Comment: As I read, as long as in every round(where log(n) randomness and constant queries allowed) prover succeed, there's no info passing between rounds? How it mention the proof be consistent?

Comment: Perhaps you should add your definition of PCP. In the usual definition there is only one round.

Comment: In each round verifier see prover prove, it's more likely the statement is really true, but more rounds are needed to more convince, wrong?

Comment: anyway there's no need that `Answers to different “routes” must be consistent`, you don't even go two routes

Comment: What’s missing is the actual definition.

Comment: Look like I mistook Interactive proof system and Probabilistically checkable proof